# disable textboxfor using a checkboxfor razor mvc and jquery

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, checkbox, textbox

I am trying to disable/enable an `@Html.TextBoxFor` in razor using an `@Html.CheckBoxFor`

I have defined my CheckBoxFor in this manner:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ResYearChecked, new { Name = "ResYearChecked", id = "ResYearChecked" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchResYear, new { Name = "SearchResYear", id = "SearchResYear" })
```

and I am trying to call the script:

```
<script>
    $('ResYearChecked').change(function () {
        $("SearchResYear").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
</script>
```

Do I need to add the `onclick` attribute to the `CheckBoxFor`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution. I enabled the attribute `readonly` for the `@Html.TextBoxFor`. I then removed the `readonly` attribute once the `@Html.CheckBoxFor` was checked.

Here is the code for my `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and `@Html.TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ResYearChecked, new { Name = "ResYearChecked", id = "ResYearChecked" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchResYear, new { Name = "SearchResYear", id = "SearchResYear", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
<script>
    $('#ResYearChecked').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#SearchResYear").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#SearchResYear").focus();
        } else {
            $("#SearchResYear").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Remove your `new { Name = "...", id = "...." }` - the methods already add the correct `name` and `id` attributes (and under no circumstances should you ever attempt to change the `name` attribute)